# PBKDF2 same salt and password, different keys

Tags: android, security, encryption, pbkdf2

I'm trying to implement a method that given a password and a salt return a key in Android (actually I want to use it to store encrypted information on a DB). I copied something from internet:

```
public SecretKey deriveKeyPbkdf2(byte[] salt, String password) {
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt,
                ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = null;
        try {
            keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                    .getInstance(PBKDF2_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();

        SecretKey result = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        return secretKey;
        //return  secretKey;
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The fact is that if I call this method with the same password and salt, it doesn't work (it gives me new keys all the time, not matching at all!).
What is wrong with it? There's something with Android that I should know?

Ok so I managed to find the "original" snippet of code that actually work (I tested it with exactly the same input of my original question)...Any hint?

```
public static byte[] deriveKeyPbkdf2(byte[] salt, String password) {
try {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt,
            ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance(PBKDF2_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM);
    byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
    Log.d(TAG, "key bytes: " + toHex(keyBytes));

    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("PBKDF2 key derivation took %d [ms].",
            elapsed));

    return keyBytes;
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the extra code from the question, that should help find (notice) the error.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();

return secretKey;
```

You should be returning `keyBytes` not `secretKey`.

Or with:

```
SecretKey result = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
return secretKey;
```

You should be returning `result` not `secretKey`.

Simplified for understanding:

```
KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM);

SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();

return keyBytes;
```